# What does the "&" mean in this Tcl statment

Tags: pipe, tcl

The line is this:

```
if [catch {open "|$command |& cat"} input] {
```

This is code fragment from http://www.beedub.com/book/2nd/TKEXAMPL.doc.html

I came so far that |$command describes a command pipeline. The output is piped into cat to output errors into the pipe immediately, according to that tutorial page.

input is the name of the file descriptor. It is open for read later on.

But it is totally opaque what the "&" symbol does in "|& cat"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it is totally opaque what the "&" symbol does in "|& cat"

The documentation on [`exec`](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl/TclCmd/exec.htm#M9) says:

> Separates distinct commands in the pipeline. Both standard output and
>   standard error of the preceding command will be piped into the
>   standard input of the next command. This form of redirection overrides
>   forms such as 2> and >&.

So, as opposed to `|`, `|&` will also pipe the standard error of `$command` into the standard input of `cat`.

Comment: Yes, it is under exec. I did not look there. In hindsight I should have done so knowing that open builds an exec command. Sigh. Thanks. It also clarifies the remainder of the text where is explained that both stdout and stderr are piped.

Comment: Just checked [the documentation for `open` on command pipelines](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/open.htm#M21) and that does explicitly call out that the pipeline spec is documented in `exec`.